# Lazy load plist dictionary element(s)

Tags: ios, objective-c

The usual method for loading data from a dictionary contained in a plist is as below:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *data= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Is there a way to import only the element(s) specified in a key / set of keys, like:

```
NSDictionary *data= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path forKey:key];
```

The idea is to perform lazy loading of dictionary contents by key.

Comment: No, a plist can only be loaded as a whole.

Comment: Not possible. If you're after optimization, make sure it *actually is a problem* before trying to optimize.

Comment: It is a problem, hence going after the optimization. I imagine the same applies for JSON files?

Comment: What is your particular issue which calls for optimization? If you think about what a plist or JSON contains, you need to walk the data to properly find items. Even if there was a method called `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path forKey:key]`, it would be forced to walk the tree (ie. load the file). Is your reason the time of loading? Memory? You comment below sort of eludes to memory.

Comment: The reason is memory. By lazy loading into a hash table, I may get rid of elements less used in memory.

Comment: The devices have a lot of memory. However I can see of you load a lot of files it can add up. I recommend a diff approach of loading the plist as is but then creating a new dict based on what you want. Then you have the minimal set you need. At the end of the day, you are probably worrying a bit too much. I use a lot of data from plists or loaded json data and don't concern about myself on these items. I generally make games where there are a lot of assets and memory usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on my comment above, you could add a class method to the NSDictionary via a category. You could do something like (not tested BTW).

```
+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path forKeys:(NSArray *)keys
{
    NSMutableDictionary *newDictionary = nil;
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

    if (dictionary) {
        newDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        for (id key in dictionary.allKeys) {
            if ([keys containsObject:key]) {
                newDictionary[key] = dictionary[key];
            }
        }
    }

    return [newDictionary copy];
}
```

If you did this, you'd see your spike in memory, but it should subside once dictionary is freed.

Alternatively, take a look at YAJL (https://github.com/lloyd/yajl). I've used this when dealing with very large JSON files. This was mainly the stream it in chunks. It is event driven, so you should be able to stream it in and detect the keys you want (hopefully).

Comment: YAJL is the way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

please try the below method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  NSMutableArray *arry;
 arry = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Catalog" ofType:@"plist"]; 
 NSDictionary *dic = [menuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 lblName.text = [dic objectForKey:@"MenuName"];
```

}

Comment: Doesn't work. The memory spikes on initWithContentsOfFile, which means that at that point everything is loaded into memory - what i was trying to avoid.